Efficient computation of sum of discounted rewards in RL
This is my current implementation of the sum of discounted rewards that I need for Reinforcement Learning, which given a reward list and discount value should do the following:
rewards: [1, 2, 3]
discount: 0.9
Objective:
First compute a discounts array like so [1, 0.9, 0.9**2]
Then, compute a sum of discounted rewards such that each element is the sum of the element-wise product of the slice rewards[i:] and discounts[:n-i].
def get_discounted_rewards(rewards, discount):
    n = len(rewards)
    sum_of_discounted_rewards = []
    rewards = np.array(rewards)
    discounts = discount ** np.arange(n)
    for i in range(n):
        sum_of_discounted_rewards.append(np.sum(rewards[i:] * discounts[:n-i]))
    return sum_of_discounted_rewards

How can I do this without the for loop (implicit or explicit)?

There's no way to do this without looping. I think what you mean is you want to move the loops to a lower level where they will be vectorized by pytorch/numpy. This does not remove the loop, but runs it more efficiently.
That said, there are still some fundamental issues with how discounting is calculated that makes it hard to vectorize.
If there are T total steps, the discounted reward at step t is given by:
discounted[t] = rewards[t] * gamma**0 + rewards[t] * gamma**1 + ... rewards[T] * gamma**(T-t)
What this means is we have to discount each reward multiple times. In your example, we need to compute 3 * .9 for the discounted reward at time 1, as well as 3 * .9**2 for the discounted reward at time 2.
If you want to do this in a fully vectorized way, you need to compute the full n by n matrix of all rewards discounted by all discount values and sum all the upper triangular diagonals. Technically you can do this in torch in one go by computing the n by n rewards/discounts matrix and convolving over it, but the overhead of those operations kills any performance gains.
After messing around a bit, I've found this to be the best option:
@numba.jit
def get_discounted_rewards(rewards, discount):
    n = rewards.shape[0]
    discounted = np.zeros(n+1)
    for i in np.arange(n-1, -1, -1):
        discounted[i] = rewards[i] + discount * discounted[i+1]
    return discounted[:-1]

Here we compute each discounted reward iteratively. This avoids the summation operation np.sum(rewards[i:] * discounts[:n-i]). Using numba to jit compile the function brings the loop to a lower level.
